# How to dynamically add method to object while preserving the same signature?

Tags: python, dynamic, parameters, signature, inspect

I just want to copy all member variables and method of a object to another.

I use `setattr()` function for member variables and `types.MethodType` for method,
but in this case, copied function has nothing in `inspect.signature`.

I want to copy the parameter list, too. How can I do that?

I make an example below:

```py
import inspect

class source:
  def func1(self, a: str, b: int):
    print(a, "%d"%b)

class dest:
  pass

s = source()
d = dest()

# copy s -> d

inspect.signature(d.func1)
# -> Out: <Signature (a:str, b:int)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are attributes of the `class` to which they are bound and that is where `inspect` looks for them. This mean you must to copy them from the `Source` *class* to the `Dest` *class*. When you do it this way, they'll both automatically have the same signature of course.

```
import inspect

class Source:
    def func1(self, a: str, b: int):
        print(a, "%d"%b)

class Dest:
    pass

s = Source()
d = Dest()

print(inspect.signature(s.func1))  # -> (self, a: str, b: int)
setattr(type(d), 'func1', Source.func1)
print(inspect.signature(d.func1))  # -> (self, a: str, b: int)
d.func1('ans', 42)  # -> ans 42
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. i check out this code working.